# Ionic 3 Error No provider for AppVersion

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I m using Ionic 3 (Lazy Loading):

I am getting this error, but cannot seem to find the error of my ways.

> Error: No provider for AppVersion!

I have:

**settings.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SettingsPage } from './settings';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [SettingsPage],
  imports: [IonicPageModule.forChild(SettingsPage)],
})
export class SettingsPageModule { }
```

**settings.ts**

```
import { AppVersion } from '@ionic-native/app-version';

constructor( public appVersion: AppVersion)
```

Answer (score 3):

Needed to add `AppVersion` to the `settings.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SettingsPage } from './settings';
import { AppVersion } from '@ionic-native/app-version';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [SettingsPage],
  imports: [IonicPageModule.forChild(SettingsPage)],
  providers: [AppVersion]
})
export class SettingsPageModule { }
```