# Ionic 3 - How to get application version number?

Tags: cordova, ionic3, ionic-native

I am using app-version plugin to get version number. I am trying as below : [plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/app-version/)

```
this.appVersion.getVersionNumber().then((res)=>{
console.log(res); 
}, (err)=>{
console.log(err); 
});
```

I am getting error :

```
class not found
```

does anyone faced same issue or is there any other way to get version number ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was forget to add in device ready event. So finally I added in device event now it is working perfectly in android and ios.

```
this.platform.ready().then(()=> {
   this.appVersion.getVersionNumber().then((res)=>{
    console.log(res); 
   }, (err)=>{
    console.log(err); 
   });
});
```

Comment: I can't believe the ionic doc does not mention about adding the AppVersion provider in app.module.ts mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44067401/ionic-3-error-no-provider-for-appversion

Answer (score -1):

```
import { AppVersion } from '@ionic-native/app-version';
export class appVersion {
   public version;

   constructor(private appVersion: AppVersion) { 
      .
      .
      this.version = this.appVersion.getVersionNumber();
   }
}
```

Using getVersionNumber function you can get the version.

Note: The App version plugin does not work on browser environments.

Comment: thanks for answer but getversionnumber is promise method.

Comment: How to use it with the browser?

Comment: @GuilhermeSampaio you can import version from package.json file and maintain proper version in package file in ionic project

Comment: @Khurshid Ansari how? I maintain it in the config.xml. Will have to use two places?

Comment: @GuilhermeSampaio You can't use this Cordova plugin with the browser.