# Retrieve the app version value in ionic 3

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I installed the npm package appversion and added the following code in one of my typescript page as

```
let versionCode = this.appVersion.getVersionCode();
console.log("Version Code",versionCode);
```

Now the output what i am get is as shown below
[image: Output]

Now i just want to store the value "0.1.03" in a variable

But if i do this code, the value is not getting displayed.

```
let versionNum = versionCode.t._zone_symbol_value;
```

How to retrieve and store it in a variable. Any hep appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The `getVersionCode()` method returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), so you need to get the value like this:

```
let versionCode = null;

this.appVersion.getVersionCode().then(result => {
  versionCode = result;
  console.log(`VersionCode: ${versionCode}`);
})
```

Comment: I can't believe the ionic doc does not mention about adding the AppVersion provider in app.module.ts mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44067401/ionic-3-error-no-provider-for-appversion

Answer (score 0):

The @ionic-native/app-version returns a promise so you could try something like this:

```
let versionNum = "";
this.appVersion.getVersionNumber().then((version) => {
  versionNum = version;
}
```